# How to get MySQL service status of remote machine?

Tags: mysql, linux

I am using separate Linux machines(Cent-OS) for my application server and Database server.

I am in-need to show remote-machine MySQL status from my application server machine.

like the output of "service mysql status"

I had remote machine MySQL access. Is it possible to get remote-dB status from my application server by running shell commands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remote/Client mysql status could be identified using following commands,

```
mysqladmin --host=db1.example.org --user=admin status
Uptime: 884637  Threads: 1  Questions: 5534424  Slow queries: 144  Opens: 4444  Flush tables: 21  Open tables: 166  Queries per second avg: 6.259


mysqladmin --host=db1.example.org --user=admin ping
mysqld is alive
```

Comment: If you need a bash one-liner to check status until the DB is ready you can use:

while ! mysqladmin --host=mysql --user=root --password=password ping; do echo 'mysqld is not ready yet..'; sleep 4; done;

Answer (score 2):

You could connect (using [mysql_real_connect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-connect.html) function or [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) command) to the server and issue a [SHOW STATUS;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-status.html) and/or [SHOW PROCESSLIST;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html) MySQL request.

Comment: I guess that yes. Try, and read the reference manual relevant to your particular version. Also, you might consider upgrading your MySQL server (perhaps using [mariadb](http://mariadb.org/)...) since 5.0 is a bit old and rusty.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use SSH to access the machine remotely you can do: `ps -ef | grep mysqld` to see if mysql is up and running.

Comment: Sorry,i dont have SSH access. I am having MySQL grant permissions only. Any other solution? I am using MySQL 5.0.X